# X and Y axis labels not displaying on line chart (Chart.js)

Tags: charts, chart.js

Example attached.  I cant for some reason get the x or y axis labels to display on the line graph (chart).  Code is shown below.  I have tried everything I can think of!
I need to display axis labels.  The label code is in there but something is off?
I at least need to have a x axis for time showing on the bottom axis.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["0", "5", "10", "15", "20", "25"],
        datasets: [{
       label: 'HR/Bpm',
            data: [72, 175, 72, 175, 72, 72],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }


]
    },
    options: {
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: '(Expected) Physical Work Load'
      },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'HR (Bpm)'
                        },
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Time (Mins)'
                        }
                    }],
        }
    },

});
</script>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gantry-width-50">
            <div class="gantry-width-spacer">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
                <canvas id="doughnut-chart" width="380" height="280"></canvas>
<script>
new Chart(document.getElementById("doughnut-chart"), {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: ["Technical", "Tactical", "Social", "Physical"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Population (millions)",
          backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#3d6b1f","#e6e600","#ff3300"],
          data: [27,67,34,14]
        }
      ]
    },

    options: {
legend: {
         display: true,
         position: "right",
labels:{
        boxWidth:10 //Width legend colorbox
    }
      },

      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Content Distribution'
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
          <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score -1):

Had two 'options' in the code and it was causing it not too run correctly. Figured it out in the editor.  Everything needs to be under one 'Options' in Chart.js. 
Solved and waiting to close.